# How insert items to tableview with bind to combobox?

Tags: javafx, combobox, tableview

when select from combobox item the tableview refresh ok.

```
ObservableList<Specie> species = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

//the tableview items depends on genderComboBox selected item
livingBeingTableView.itemsProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
            Gender gender = genderComboBox.getValue();
            if (gender == null) {
                return FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            } else {
                int id = gender.getId();
                //seachSpeciesIdGender(int id) find the species with the id associated
                species = SpecieDAO.searchSpeciesIdGender(id);
                return species;
            }
        }, genderComboBox.valueProperty()));
```

the problem is. When insert new item and add it to tableview

```
    private void handleNewSpecie() {
            Specie tempSpecie = new Specie();
            boolean okClicked = main.showSpecieEditDialog(tempSpecie);
            if (okClicked) {
                SpecieDAO.insertSpecie(tempSpecie.getCommonName(), tempSpecie.getScientName(),
                        genderComboBox.getValue().getId(), 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 0);
                int id = genderComboBox.getValue().getId();
                species = SpecieDAO.searchSpeciesIdGender(id)
                livingBeingTableView.setItems(species);
            }
        }
```

A bound value cannot be set

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: TableView.items : A bound value cannot be set.
    at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:143)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableView.setItems(TableView.java:862)
    at cu.edu.cujae.guatini.controller.MainController.handleNewSpecie(MainController.java:213)
    ... 62 more
```

Is possible to insert items with bind tableview to combobox? What am i doing wrong? Thanks and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the value of a property that is bound without unbinding it. (Binding means keeping the value of the bound property the same as the other property's value.)
You should probably simply add a listener to the `value` property and refresh the list this listener:

```
private void refreshTable() {
    Gender gender = genderComboBox.getValue();
    ObservableList<Specie> species = (gender == null) ? FXCollections.emptyObservableList() : SpecieDAO.searchSpeciesIdGender(gender.getId());
    livingBeingTableView.setItems(species);
}
```

```
genderComboBox.valueProperty().addListener((o, a, newValue) -> refreshTable());
```

```
private void handleNewSpecie() {
    Specie tempSpecie = new Specie();
    boolean okClicked = main.showSpecieEditDialog(tempSpecie);
    if (okClicked) {
        SpecieDAO.insertSpecie(tempSpecie.getCommonName(), tempSpecie.getScientName(),
                genderComboBox.getValue().getId(), 0, 0,
                0, 0, 0);
        refreshTable();
    }
}
```

---

Depending on the size of the data it may be an option to keep both genders in memory and use a `FilteredList` to show the appropriate gender. This would allow you to simply modify the backing list of the `FilteredList` on edits and bind it's `predicate` property:

```
ObservableList<Specie> species = FXCollections.observableArrayList(getAllSpecies());

// create filtered view of all species
FilteredList<Specie> filteredSpecies = new FilteredList<>(species);
filteredSpecies.predicateProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
    Gender gender = genderComboBox.getValue();
    if (gender == null) {
        return o -> false;
    } else {
        int id = gender.getId();
        return o -> o.getGenderId() == id;
    }
}, genderComboBox.valueProperty()));

livingBeingTableView.setItems(filteredSpecies);
```

```
if (okClicked) {
    SpecieDAO.insertSpecie(tempSpecie.getCommonName(), tempSpecie.getScientName(),
            genderComboBox.getValue().getId(), 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0);

    species.setAll(getAllSpecies());
}
```

---

BTW: *Specie* is a financial term. The biological species is plural only.